# function called twice with urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, function

I have a small piece of code detecting event on a specific GPIO of my raspberry. When the event is detected, a function named increase_counter is called, if inside the function i only keep the "print('Flash ... ')" i only have one print per event,but if i call a url with urllib2 the whole increase_counter is executed twice, so i will have 2 flashes counted.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import urllib2,json

def increase_counter(ch):
    print('Flash ... ')
    requete='http://192.168.1.20:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=udevice&idx=52&svalue=1'
    response=urllib2.urlopen(requete)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    print data

IRPIN = 4


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #GPIO SETUP
GPIO.setup(IRPIN,GPIO.IN) #GPIO SETUP

GPIO.add_event_detect(IRPIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=increase_counter, bouncetime=3) #Calling event when flash is detected

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(' Stopped !!!')
except:
    print(' Stopped !!!')
    raise
finally:
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(IRPIN)
    GPIO.cleanup(IRPIN) # GPIO cleanup
```

Comment: Comment urllib2.urlopen line to see if it is indeed because of that

Comment: I did that, when i comment urllib line print('Flash ...') only append once

Comment: Using threading, my url call is now asynchronous it looks like the problem is gone. So problem seem to be solved but i still don't understand why